# How do I fill areas in a image converted from a hand-drawn picture in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, image-trace

I have to edit a pencil drawing. I scanned the drawing, traced the bitmap and obtained an image similar to this: 
[image]

How can I fill the areas marked in the diagram with a fill or gradient? (The lines shown in red are Objects, not Strokes).

Answer (score 1):

As long as the objects/lines form enclosed shapes (and have no gaps), you could use the bucket fill tool. If there are open areas/areas with gaps that you want to fill, you could just draw some lines to close them with the Pencil or the Bézier tool.

[image]

The Bucket fill tool options has a Close Gaps function, but sometimes it doesn't work so well. For the best results ensure that all areas you want to fill are closed.

Comment: Sorry but this does not work. using the fill and stroke tool causes a coloured outline to be drawn within my own outline. it does not fill the are surrounded by the line. I am working from a trace of a scan of a hand done ink drawing, not from a shape created by a shape tool, or a beziere tool. This coloured outline eventually swamps my own brush drawing and I lose it.irritating on both counts.